# How can download code source of Autofac , Caliburn.Micro for Framework3.5

Tags: c#, autofac, caliburn.micro

I want to download Autofac and Caliburn.Micro source codes,but I only got source codes for framework4.0.

**I don't know where I can download them(source code) for framework3.5**

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/BuildingFromSource? You'll also need SandCastle for .Net 3.5 (a link to which is on that page)

Caliburn is here: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets